# Matrix representation of the following equation - for finding optimal weights for regularized linear regression

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, parameter-estimation

If I have the following equation,

$$E(w)=\sum_{i=1}^n (y_n -\beta^T x_n) +\lambda \sum_{i=1}^d \beta_i^2  $$

which is the cost function of **regularized** linear regression ($\beta$ and $x_n$ are vectors, "$n \times d$" is the dimension of the feature matrix),

To find optimal **$\beta$**, I can take a derivative of the above function w.r.t. $\beta$

and represent it as ([further information](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/VideoPage.php?course=MachineLearning&video=05.4-Regularization-RegularizedLinearRegression&speed=100):  at **7:05**):

$$\left(Y- \beta^TX\right)X = \lambda\left[\begin{matrix} 0 &  &  &  &  \\  & 1 &  &  &  \\  &  & 1 &  &  \\  &  &  & \ddots &  \\  &  &  &  & 1 \end{matrix}\right]\beta$$

---

However, If I have

$$E(w)=\sum_{i=1}^n ( y_{ n }-\beta^T x_n) +\lambda \sum_{i=1}^d \beta_i^2 + \mu \sum_{i=1}^{d-1} (\beta_i -\beta_{i+1})^2 $$

**How do I represent this in a neat matrix form? I'm struggling to write it because of the presence of the extra  term $(\beta_i-\beta_{i+1})^2$**

Comment: Is $\beta_{d+1}$ well-defined?

Comment: Hi, no. The differentiation is w.r.t $\beta_i$ and the last term would be $\beta_d$. 

$\beta_{d+1}$ is not defined.

Comment: Even before you differentiate, $E(w)$ itself has to make sense. If you don't specify $\beta_{d+1}$ then the summation should be indexed from $1$ to $d-1$.

Comment: You're right. Edited. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last term, you can use a matrix $M$ (dimension $d\times d$) constructed as follows:

1. The principal diagonal of $M$ is $(1,1,\ldots,1,0)$ ($1$ everywhere except for the last entry).
2. The entries immediately to the right of the principal diagonal are all $-1$. (There are $d-1$ such entries.)
3. The remaining entries are all $0$'s.

Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{d-1}(\beta_i-\beta_{i+1})^2=|M\beta|^2=\beta'M'M\beta.
$$
Differentiating $\beta'M'M\beta$ w.r.t. $\beta$ gives $2M'M\beta$.